# Access instance constant in lazy constructor

Tags: swift

Consider this example

```
class Foo {
    private let bar = "bar"

    lazy var baz : String = {
        return "baz \(bar)"
    }()
}
```

Unfortunately this won't compile and give the following error

```
'Foo.Type' does not have a member named 'bar'
```

I really do not want to declare `bar` outside the class (globally). Is there no other way to keep this inside the class and why isn't `bar` accessible in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: preface with `self`

Swift can be quite misleading with error messages, but in this case, the answer can be deduced from the message.  It is looking for `bar` on type Foo.Type, whereas you are trying to reference an instance variable.  Here is code that works:

```
class Foo {
    private let bar = "bar"

    lazy var baz : String = {
        return "baz \(self.bar)"
    }()
}
```

Comment: aaah... thanks. The devil is in the details - or misleading error messages.

Answer (score 1):

In lazy props you need to say self

```
lazy var baz : String = {
    let bar = self.bar
    return "baz \(bar)"
}()
```